# Filtering records on date in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to filter records on the basis of date. However, I am unable to do so. Following is the code:

```
 data2  =       data1.filter(function(row) { console.log(row["wsrweek"],parseDate("05-30-2014"));
            return  row["wsrweek"] == parseDate("05-30-2014");})
```

log output:

```
Date 2014-05-29T18:30:00.000Z Date 2014-05-29T18:30:00.000Z utilization.js:122
Date 2014-05-22T18:30:00.000Z Date 2014-05-29T18:30:00.000Z utilization.js:122
Date 2014-05-15T18:30:00.000Z Date 2014-05-29T18:30:00.000Z utilization.js:122
Date 2014-05-08T18:30:00.000Z Date 2014-05-29T18:30:00.000Z utilization.js:122
```

First row is have equal records. However, its not getting returned as data2 is empty. Kindly suggest

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: Here Lars.. I have created this.. http://bl.ocks.org/rajatgupta13/d87de5dc6fa153ba81bc Didnt included this earlier as I thought it will be too cumbersome. There is no data coming in #utilizationtable  table. Also, can you  suggest some animation and css styling.